# Prove that $\{x\in\mathbb{R}:\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}f_{k}(x)=+\infty\}$ is countable intersetion of $F_{\sigma}$ sets.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\{f_{k}\}$ be a sequence of real valued continuous functions on $\mathbb{R}$. Prove that $\{x\in\mathbb{R}:\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}f_{k}(x)=+\infty\}$ is countable intersetion of $F_{\sigma}$ sets.

In metric space, I every open set is $F_{\sigma}$. Then, the countable intersection of open sets is $G_{\delta}$ set. How can we show this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\{x\in{\bf{R}}:\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}f_{k}(x)=\infty\}&=\bigcap_{N}\bigcup_{M}\bigcap_{k\geq M}\{x\in{\bf{R}}:f_{k}(x)\geq N\}.
\end{align*}
Note that 
\begin{align*}
\bigcap_{k\geq M}\{x\in{\bf{R}}:f_{k}(x)\geq N\}
\end{align*}
is closed by the continuity of each $f_{k}$.